# Twilio: Send SMS from connected account

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Here's what I'm trying:

```
curl -X POST -d "Body=Hi there, this is a test message from cURL" -d 'From=+1aaabbbcccc' -d "To=+1zzzxxxyyyy" "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$TWILIO_CONNECTED_SUBACCOUNT_SID/Messages" -u "$TWILIO_CONNECTED_MAIN_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"
```

Where `$TWILIO_CONNECTED_SUBACCOUNT_SID` is a account SID with the phone number I want to send from. `$TWILIO_CONNECTED_MAIN_ACCOUNT_SID` is the account SID that the connect button sent back to me (has a name like "Subaccount for ConnectApp: ..."). `$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN` is my (not the connected account's) auth token.

I've tried various permutations of the 3 account SIDs but can't get any of them to work. How do I send an SMS on behalf of a connected account?

---

I got it to work if I purchase a new number for the `$TWILIO_CONNECTED_MAIN_ACCOUNT_SID` account via cURL. But I don't want to build a UI for purchasing numbers in my app, I want to let users just pick a number they already own on Twilio, from their main account. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[According to the docs, under permissions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/connect#charge-account-for-usage):

> ### Charge account for usage
>
> This allows your Connect App to perform actions that charge your user’s Twilio account such as make and receive phone calls, send and receive SMS messages, and buy phone numbers. ***Your Connect App will not have access to resources in the user’s parent account, like phone numbers***. Instead, your Connect App must buy phone numbers on behalf of the user, using the Account SID passed to your Authorize URL.

Emphasis mine.

So, you cannot use a connect account to send messages from existing resources. You will need to buy a new number to send.

An alternative to using Connect here, that would give you access to the account's resources would be to have the user submit their Account SID and an [API Key/Secret pair](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/keys/api-key). While it's never ideal to share credentials, an API Key/Secret pair can be easily deactivated without affecting the rest of the account.

Comment: *Sigh* That's what I feared. Thanks for confirming it though. It really ought to be an additional permission I can request.